# Change margins on the first of \tableofcontents page only

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I need to change a page bottom margin, but do that **for the first page of ToC only**. Sure thing the following does not work as it adjusts all pages of ToC:

```
{
  % bottom margin must be bigger
  \changepage{-35mm}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
  \tableofcontents
}
```

So `\changepage` should be somehow "injected" into `\tableofcontens` to detect and apply to the first page only.

I need some special LaTeX magic. Please assist.

**Update.** \changepage may not be used with `\addtocontens`, but Stefan's suggestion helped:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{-35mm}}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
```

I have another problem now (create a separate question?): i'm looking for some general approach, kind of "apply these change to the current page only; limit the scope they affect". Namely: i have to put [such frame](http://anatolykh.narod.ru/Images/UG/03-Shtamp.jpg) on the first ToC page, and [such one](http://anatolykh.narod.ru/Images/UG/03-Shtamp2.jpg) on the rest of ToC pages. (I have frames as PDFs, so i just don't know how to ask LaTeX to place them in required order; tried `afterpage` and `wallpaper` packages.)

Comment: Har you thought about messing with the distance between items in the ToC? Usually they do not contain any shrink or stretch, adding that often helps of the ToC spills a few lines onto page two.

Comment: With regard to your update, you should indeed ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @daeif If i got you right, it won't help as my ToC is 4 pages long ATM (:

Comment: then I do not understand your need to make the first page longer? I may end up looking odd in the over all design

Comment: @daleif, i needed that in regard of [different frames per ToC pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19789/toc-frame-1-for-the-first-page-and-frame-2-for-the-rest-ones). Such (if you wish) strange requirements of my master's thesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\addtocontents` for this. `\enlargethispage` is another command you could use. For example:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{35mm}}
```