# ToC: frame #1 for the first page and frame #2 for the rest ones

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I have to put [such frame](http://anatolykh.narod.ru/Images/UG/03-Shtamp.jpg) on the first ToC page, and [such one](http://anatolykh.narod.ru/Images/UG/03-Shtamp2.jpg) on the rest of ToC pages (a thesis requirement). As i generate ToC via `\tableofcontents`, i have to clue how to reach that.

I have that frames as PDFs, so i may use `wallpaper`/`graphicsx`/whatever package to depict them. The problem is: how to make LaTeX place frames in the required way?

NB: currently my ToC is 4 pages long, that's why i need in a general solution: *`\tableofcontents --> p1 f#1, p2 f#2, p3 f#2, p4 f#2, ...`*

Comment: Do you use any packages for headers and footers? Do you use a class like `scrreprt`? You can define a special footer for the chapter page and a pagestyle for the rest.

Comment: @Marco Don't understand how that my help. I do not need another chapter page, i need to change how ToC is generated only. (I use `extarticle` class and standard `\pagestyle{myheadings}` if any.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example, I use the `scrpage2` package (part of KOMA-script) to define different sets of page styles for the ToC and the rest of the document. You probably have to adjust the "rest-of-document" header and footer according to your needs (which you didn't specify). Also note that the information you gave in your comment (documentclass `extarticle`) was crucial, because a class without the `\chapter` command in your case requires manually forcing `thispagestyle{scrplain}` for the first ToC page.

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

% In the following code, \rule{8cm}{1cm} stands for the header of the first ToC page
%     (with page style scrplain), \rule{4cm}{1cm} for the header of the other ToC pages
%     (with page style scrheadings)
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead[\rule{8cm}{1cm}]{\rule{4cm}{1cm}}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\setlength{\headheight}{36pt}

\thispagestyle{scrplain}
\tableofcontents

% Redefine scrheadings and scrplain for the rest of the document
\clearpage
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{\headmark}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}

\section{foo}

% Force a page break in the ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage}

\section{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I asked him whether he is using a package such `scrpage2` or not. Do you see his answer?

Comment: @Marco: I saw it, but contrary to the use of a particular document class or (perhaps) the use of a particular package, I do not consider the fact that a questioner is *not* using a particular package as a binding constraint for an answerer, unless the questioner expressly says so ("I want a solution that *doesn't* rely on a package for customizing header and footer").

Comment: This hack helped after some adoptation. Thanks a lot, wizards (: