# How to avoid widow lines in Table of contents (TOC)

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, widows-orphans

I have a Table of Contents page (the last page, page 3) which just has one line on it.  Is there a way of manually editing it so, say, Chapter 3 starts on page 2, as opposed to straddling pages 1 and 2? This would presumably push the rest of everything down and lead to a more "balanced" page 3.

Here are some relevant [I hope!] files:

```
\let\oldtableofcontents = \tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{ 
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{singlespace} 
\oldtableofcontents 
\end{singlespace}}
```

Comment: I, and I guess many others too, do not understand the question. Be more specific and maybe post a picture explaining what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried enlarging the *first* page of the ToC by one line, by inserting the instruction `\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}` immediately before `\tableofcontents`? This might just suffice to let LaTeX typeset the entire ToC on two pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of options, but in answer to your question, you can insert a page break in the ToC at any point within the document flow by using:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
```

You would add the above just before `\chapter{<chapter 3>}` (see also [How can I force ToC not to end with a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17071/5764)). An alternative would be to insert a `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` in the ToC

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}}
```

at the appropriate location (see also [Change margins on the first of `\tableofcontents` page only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19762/5764)). However, this may not be suitable as it would yield an uneven page block in the ToC.